# Stop Previous Fragment Service on Tab Changes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

When I change Tab, the previous tab's fragment service is still running in background, which I do not want.

What can I do if I want to stop previous fragment class service on Tab changes?

Here's my code:

```
   tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            TextView tabTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tabTitle);

            //  System.out.println( tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());

            tabTitle.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_tittle)[tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()]);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but each time a fragment is not visible on screen it will call it's `onPause()` method, which you could use to start or stop your service.

Comment: on my first tab i play a stream video. but when i change tab video is running in background. i want to stop that fragment class service.
I think you can understand me

Comment: Your video player class should have stop method that stop the video from playing. You need to override `onPause()` method of your `Fragment` and call that stop function.

Answer (score 0):

```
onPause(){
    finish();    
}
```

you can use this to completely terminate your particular tab, and you will have to call the tab once again when you try to return back to that tab.
or

```
onPause(){
    stop();
}
void stop(){
 your code to stop the video.
}
```